# TargetType does not match type of element

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simply buttonStyle defined for `TargetType` of `Button`; but setting the style to button gives an exeption.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Magenta"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="1" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

> Additional information: 'Button' TargetType does not match type of
>   element 'Control'.

---

Further, setting the `TargetType` as `Control` removes the run-time error, but visual style of button doesn't change when it gets `Focus`.

---

Style works when set as `Button.Style`

---

**Edit**
I have two specific questions:

1. I agree to the fact that `FocusVisualStyle` is a property of `FrameworkElement` and `FrameworkContentElement`, but why is there an error setting it on button, despite the fact that Style is a *namedstyle* and not a *typedstyle* ?
2. Why does `FocusVisualStyle` don't get rendered on the `Button`? Is the `Button.FocusVisualStyle` over-ridden internally by any higher priority value like Templates, Triggers or Template Triggers ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a `FocusVisualStyle` allows you to provide visual feedback to the user when a **control** is focused. For example, adding a `Rectangle` which looks like a border of the control.

A `Style` is the look and feel of the control itself. It's all explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567(v=vs.110).aspx).

`FocusVisualStyle` is not the style for the `Button` itself, it's the style for when the `Button` is focused.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744790(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

I think what you are after is a `Trigger`.

```
<Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Magenta"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then, you can set the `Style` of your `Button`, like so:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: I agree, but when the Button gets focus, its style doesn't change. Or am I getting the concept wrong ?

Comment: To clarify, the `FocusVisualStyle` cannot affect the style of the `Button`. It only adds to the existing style of the `Button`. The problem you are having is that you are trying to set a `Button` style to the `FocusVisualStyle` which only accepts a `Control` style. I hope I explained that well enough.

Comment: It was not working for me for a while as I was setting the same property of the style in line for the button control. In-line property value was overriding what gets set by the style trigger "buttonStyle". Sweet answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should use it like this

```
        <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Magenta" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

and set it like this:

```
<Button Content="1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"/>
```

To see this better:

```
         <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Magenta" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The focus visual style feature provides a common "object model" for
>   introducing visual user feedback based on keyboard navigation to any
>   UI element. This is possible without applying a new template to the
>   control, or knowing the specific template composition.

Comment: But then whats the meaning of FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the difference between button and focus visual style, consider this:

```
<Style x:Key="rectFocusVisual" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
  <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="1 3" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="focusVisual">
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rectFocusVisual}" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="button" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

and:

```
<Button
  Content="I am a green button with red focus rectangle"
  FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource focusVisual}"
  Style="{StaticResource button}" />
<ComboBox FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource focusVisual}" />
```

The difference will be apparent when the button is given focus. The button should appear green and if focused will show a red focus rectangle. If the combo box gets focus, it will have a similar red rectangle.

While the button style can only be used for Button elements, the focusVisual style can be used for any element that supports it. This way a consistent focus style can be used for any element, regardless of its underlying control type.